# SQL Server : rename primary key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, primary-key, rename, ddl

I have a table `doc.MyTable` which I want to deprecate by renaming to `doc._MyTable`. I then want to create a new `doc.MyTable` with the same primary key that the old `doc.MyTable` had. The problem is that SQL Server says that primary key already exists. So that means I need to rename the old primary key too.

I tried the following:

```
EXEC SP_RENAME 'doc.MyTable', '_MyTable'

-- Method 1
EXEC SP_RENAME 'PK_MyTable', 'PK__MyTable'

-- Method 2
ALTER TABLE [doc].[_MyTable] DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable]
ALTER TABLE [doc].[_MyTable] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK__MyTable]
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [document_id] ASC,
    [line_id] ASC,
    [sub_line_id] ASC
)

-- Create new table
CREATE TABLE [doc].[MyTable] (
    ... columns
CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
    ... key columns
)
... extra conditions
```

Method 1 throws this error:

> No item by the name of 'PK_MyTable' could be found in the current database 'db_dev', given that @itemtype was input as '(null)'.

While method 2 throws this:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_MyTable'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'PK.MyTable'. 
> The duplicate key value is (10358930, 336000, 0).`

When I try to create the new primary key for the new table.

I'm only using one of the two "Methods" at a time. How do I fix the issue?

Comment: Method 1 and Method 2 is not clear.

Comment: The Methods are referring to the 'tries' in the code above. I changed it all to "Method" to make it more clear.

Answer (score 25):

Try following solution:

```
EXEC sp_rename '[TableSchema].[TableName].[ConstraintName]', 'NewConstraintName'
```

Example:

```
EXEC sp_rename '[doc].[_MyTable].[PK_MyTable]', '[PK__MyTable]'
```

Answer (score 3):

When renaming your primary key, prefix the primary key name with the schema and table name like so:

```
create schema doc authorization dbo;
go
create table doc.MyTable (
    id int not null
  , constraint pk_MyTable primary key clustered (Id)
);
exec sp_rename N'doc.MyTable.pk_MyTable', N'pk__MyTable';
exec sp_rename N'doc.MyTable', N'_MyTable', N'object';
create table doc.MyTable (
    id int not null
  , constraint pk_MyTable primary key clustered (Id)
);
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/OBIB87116

If you were using the default schema `dbo`, you would not need to prefix the schema and table name to rename the primary key with `sp_rename`.

Comment: You don't need to use `N'[_MyTable]'`, this will create a table called ... `[[_MyTable]]`. Just use `'_MyTable'`.  `_MyTable` doesn't need escaping anyway, you can write `select * from doc._MyTable`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Corrected

Answer (score -3):

Cant you delete it from your original table and re-create it with the name you want?

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourOldTable
DROP CONSTRAINT YourConstraintname;
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. Besides, there's nothing wrong with `sp_rename`

Comment: I didn't say there was. Deleting the index and reading  with a different name is a perfectly valid, if not preferred, answer.

Comment: Actually it's a very bad and expensive answer. It means that the index has to be *rebuilt*, a very expensive operation. Primary keys are typically clustered index which means *the entire table* has to be converted to a heap then back to a clustered index structure

Comment: Isn't this the same as my second try?

Comment: @user3685285 sqlzim posted the correct answer. You have to use a three-part name if you use schemas other than `dbo`, ie `schema.table.name`